# Show that Toeplitz Operator is Norm-Decreasing.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle of $\mathbb{C}$, Let $H^2 \subset L^2(\mathbb{T})$ be the Hardy space (i.e. $H^2 = \text{span}\{(2π)^{−1/2}z^n \in L^2 | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$). Let $f \in L^\infty$ and let $T_{f}(x)$ be a $H^2 \rightarrow H^2$ operator defined as
$$T_f(x)=P(fx), x∈H^2$$

I need to show that the operator $f \mapsto T_f$ is norm decreasing, i.e. $\|T_f\| \le \|f\|$.

I have tried to decompose $f$ into it's orthonormal components, i.e. let $f = g + g^\perp$ with $g \in H^2$. But then I got $P(fx) = P(gx + g^\perp x) = gx$ and so $LHS = \underset{\|x\| = 1}\max \|gx\|$ and $RHS = \|g + g^\perp\| \le \|g\| + \|g^\perp\| \le \|g\| = \underset{z \in \mathbb{T}}\max\|g(z)\|$. Unfortunately it seems that I getting close to the opposite of what I am trying to show. Is there a way to go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\|T_{f}(x)\|_{L^{2}}=\|P(fx)\|_{L^{2}}\leq\|P\|\|fx\|_{L^{2}}\leq\|fx\|_{L^{2}}\leq\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\|x\|_{L^{2}},
\end{align*}
so $\|T_{f}\|\leq\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$. Note that the projection has norm less than $1$.

Comment: How do you get the last inequality? (it looks like it can be derived from Cauchy-Schwartz but I am not sure how)

Comment: Holder's inequality if you want.

Comment: Is it correct to derived it like this: $\|fx\|_{L^2} \le \|fx\|_{L^1} \le \|f\|_{L^2}\|x\|_{L^2} \le \|f\|_{L^\infty}\|x\|_{L^2}$ ?

Comment: Not really, anyway, a simple inequality will do: $\displaystyle\int|f(t)|^{2}|x(t)|^{2}dt\leq\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}^{2}\displaystyle\int|x(t)|^{2}dt\cdots$